# Can't post on Stack Overflow, editor thinks I have unformatted code

Tags: bug, stack-overflow

Yet another "Stack Overflow thinks I have unformatted code" post.

I'll be short and sweet: this is the text I'm trying to post, formatted exactly the way I'd like:

https://rentry.co/td7ft/raw

This is the error I'm getting:

[image: Error message]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems to be regarding the tables as code. Probably a bug.

Comment: @tripleee If that's the case it would be very unfortunate, since my post doesn't make sense without a table.

Comment: Please try to apply some backticks to the IP or ID values.

Comment: Seems like the code in your question is already formatted, if the Rentry link you posted is accurate. Could be the table, but I don't see anything wrong with that at first glance either.

Comment: @honk yep that was it, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try one or all of the following options:

- Remove the markup from the first line (so no `*file1*`, etc.).
- Before a table, always include a blank line:

  ```
  **File1:**

  |ID|IP|Name|Comments|OS|Title|Status|
  |--|--|----|--------|--|-----|------|
  |1|127.0.0.1|Something||Windows 3.11|Title 1|Active
  ```
- In the table cells add code markup and a space on anything that has punctuation characters in it:

  ```
  |1| `127.0.0.1` |
  ```
- Sentences start with a capital letter and end with a point/dot.
- If everything else fails, remove all text and add it back paragraph by paragraph. You can trigger the check by moving the focus out of the question box. This allows you to pinpoint the exact cause.

I wish you 6 to 8 hours of experimenting.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had to put backticks to the IP addresses in the tables.